# TextBox leave causes PropertyChanged get fired twice

Tags: c#, winforms, binding

When the `Text` property of a `TextBox` is bound to an object property which that object implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, the event `PropertyChanged` may fire two times while having the same value:
 **1)** when the text is changed inside the `TextBox` **2)** when the control is leaving from it.

Consider these methods of a form:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
        TextBox secondTextBox = new TextBox();
        secondTextBox.Location = new Point(0, 100);

        this.Controls.Add(textBox);
        this.Controls.Add(secondTextBox);

        MyClass instance = new MyClass();
        instance.PropertyChanged += instance_PropertyChanged;

        textBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", instance, "Id", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    }

    private void instance_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.PropertyName + " changed");
    }
```

and the back-end class:

```
private class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    int _id;
    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Id"));
        }
    }
}
```

To reproduce the problem, type something in the upper textbox, check the console, and then enter the lower textbox and check again the console. Upon leaving, a property change is reported. Why?

Comment: Bounding is OK. Why updating the source is occurred twice?

Answer (score 1):

The default value of *Binding.DataSourceUpdateMode* property is *OnValidation*. In this configuration the data source is being only updated when *Validating* event occurs. In your example you use *OnPropertyChanged* mode, so you **additionally** request update of the data source whenever the text is changed inside the TextBox.

It is the default behaviour i.e. the *Binding* class was implemented in this way. If you want more details, you can examine *Binding.Target_PropertyChanged* and *Binding.Target_Validate* methods with a reflector.

From my perspective this behaviour isn't a problem but you need to change the implementation of the setter in the following way:

```
set
{
    if(_id != value)
    {
        _id = value;
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Id"));
    }
}
```

Even if we assume that the implementation of *Binding* class is wrong, I think that it is a good practise to check whether a value has changed before generating *PropertyChanged* event.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Michal's answer, I found the solution in switching off the `CausesValidation` property of `TextBox` as:

```
textBox.CausesValidation = false;
```